# goog.net.xhrio.send not calling the server

Tags: google-closure, plovr

I am calling goog.net.XhrIo from within this onclick event

```
goog.events.listen(invBtn, goog.ui.Component.EventType.ACTION,
        function(e) {

   goog.net.XhrIo.sent('http://remotehost.com:8080/customer/add');
 (update :typo here send instead of sent )
```

This is the very basic task I want to accomplish but this call doesn't even reach the server. I also tried passing url as goog.Uri , doesn't help.
I wonder what is stopping from making this call to the server, I tried both host name and ip address but neither helps. It just does nothing.

Is there any thing I can do to see why this call fails to even reach the server.

Appreciate any help

regards
Eddie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [plovr](http://plovr.com/) config file, set the warning level to `VERBOSE`:

```
// config.js
{
  "paths": "js",
  "mode": "ADVANCED",
  "level": "VERBOSE"
}
```

With `VERBOSE` warnings enabled, running your program shows the following warning:

```
JSC_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY: Property sent never defined on goog.net.XhrIo ...
goog.net.XhrIo.sent('http://remotehost.com:8080/customer/add');
^
```

Try changing `goog.net.XhrIo.sent();` to `goog.net.XhrIo.send();`.

In addition, you may want to pass a callback function to the XhrIo send function as follows:

```
goog.net.XhrIo.send('http://remotehost.com:8080/customer/add', function(e) {    
  var xhr = /** @type {goog.net.XhrIo} */ (e.target);
  alert(xhr.getResponseText());
});
```

Another common pattern is to create an xhr object and register an event listener:

```
var xhr = new goog.net.XhrIo();
goog.events.listenOnce(xhr, goog.net.EventType.COMPLETE, function(e) {
  var xhr = /** @type {goog.net.XhrIo} */ (e.target);
  alert(xhr.getResponseText());
  xhr.dispose(); // Dispose of the XHR if it is not going to be reused.
});
xhr.send('http://remotehost.com:8080/customer/add');
```

#### Further Reading

[Closure: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449381871), Chapter 7: ***Client-Server Communication***

Comment: Thanks cpeisert. I tried it all. 'sent' was a typo here and I updated. I used send all the while and tried almost every possible goog.net. Only jsonp is actually calling the server. My problem is xhr call does not call the server and I found it out when I see the logs from the server.   This is the actual call I made ( xhr.send(parUrl,"POST", goog.json.serialize(data), {'Content-Type':'application/json'}); )initially, but now after repeated fails all I want to see is xhr calling my server. Used settings you mentioned in Plovr and have been following the Michael Bolin's book.No luck yet. Thanks

Comment: Did you try passing a callback function to test for `xhr.isSuccess()` and comparing `xhr.getLastErrorCode() == goog.net.ErrorCode.ABORT` and `xhr.getLastErrorCode() == goog.net.ErrorCode.TIMEOUT` as shown on page 158 of *Closure: The Definitive Guide*?

Comment: Thanks again cpeisert. I tried using getLastErrorCode and it gave me result 0. I think its a cross domain issue. Otherwise it should not be so complicated to make a call. Or it could be something that is blocking call from within server. But I really appreciate your help. Best Regards.(I can't voteup because I don't have much credits yet, once I have , I will up vote your answer)